# Calculating confidence intervals for a proportion when there are no 'successes' in the sample

Tags: inference, uniform-distribution

I'm looking to analyse 400k replies to a Facebook-equivalent post to determine how many of them are written by bots, and how many of them are written by real people.

I don't have the resources to obtain all 400k replies, so I can only work with a sample (say, 4000 replies). I believe it's very likely that virtually all, but definitely not all of the replies are written by bots, but I need to prove it with some numbers.

From my reading, I understand that usually what you would do would be to:

- take, say, 40 chunks of 100 replies as your sample,
- for each sample, determine what percentage is written by bots
- calculate the mean and standard deviation of the percentages of all 40 chunks
- calculate the standard error for the sample, based on the standard deviation / sqrt of 40 (chunks)
- calculate 95% significance of the mean percentage via mean of sample chunks +/- 1.96 x standard error

To what I understand, this can be done because we expect the data to be roughly normal. With skewed data, you need more samples (chunks, in this case). However, I'm expecting that the % of bots for each chunk will be 100% each time for my 40 samples (let's assume my expectation is right). So what I'm finding is that the sample results are uniform -->

Standard deviation = 0 --> SE = 0 --> 99.999% confidence interval = 100%, 100%, 100%.

How do you infer on a population when all the sample means are uniform (i.e., all 100%), other than to conclude that the population's mean is also exactly the same (i.e., 100%). But I've only reviewed 400 / 400k replies. I can't really say that I am 99.999% confident that the % of bots for the population is 100% right?

Comment: Are you saying that _all_ your observed responses come from bots? If so, all I can think of to help you is using Bayesian statistics: get a uniform prior for the probability (or whatever is a typical noninformative prior for probabilities), apply the data, and this will give you the posterior distribution for the probability. From this you can gather a credible interval. I don't know of a way in frequentist statistics to support a case that is not in your data (without cheating)...

Comment: Could you explain in what way is the assertion of uniformity in the title intended to apply to the content of this question?

Comment: @Nick I don't know what you'd consider cheating, but all that's needed from a frequentist point of view is a straightforward confidence interval on a hypergeometric proportion, as per Glen B's reply.

Comment: @kevlaria: In the light of the answer & comments I'd suggest you change the question title to something like "Calculating confidence intervals for a proportion when there are no 'successes' in the sample".  Then it should be more helpful to others with the same question.

Comment: Title updated. Thanks for the advice. Incidentally, what's meant (in newbie-speak) by 'confidence interval on a hypergeometric proportions'?

Answer (score 3):

> From my reading, I understand that usually what you would do would be to: - take, say, 40 chunks of 100 replies as your sample, - for each sample, determine what percentage is written by bots - calculate the mean and standard deviation of the percentages of all 40 chunks - calculate the standard error for the sample, based on the standard deviation / sqrt of 40 (chunks) - calculate 95% significance of the mean percentage via mean of sample chunks +/- 1.96 x standard error

It's almost certainly not necessary to break it up into chunks.

> To what I understand, this can be done because we expect the data to be roughly normal.

Not when your proportion is very close to zero or 1. If the expected count of not-written-by-bots is no more than a handful, assuming normality isn't tenable.

> I can't really say that I am 99.999% confident that the % of bots for the population is 100% right?

There's a commonly used approximate rule to get bounds on the proportion of "successes" when you observe only failures... sometimes called the "[rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28statistics%29)".

This rule says that if no successes occur in $n$ observations, then $[0, 3/n]$ is an approximate 95% confidence interval for the proportion of successes in the population.

There are a number of ways of arriving at this rule, including using a Bayesian derivation of a credible interval.

If you get all of your sample of 4000 being bot-posts, you would have a 95% interval for the population proportion of non-bot posts of about $[0, 0.00075]$, or between 99.925% and 100% bot-posts in the population.

To do something more sophisticated, I'd suggest considering Nick Sabbe's comment relating to a Bayesian approach. If you have any prior information about the proportion you can incorporate it (not that it will make much difference with a large sample size); you can also incorporate homogeneity of proportion in this framework relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick responses. I wasn't aware of the 'rule of 3' - that seems like a very useful approximation.

I used 'uniform' only to illustrate that the distribution of the means of the chunks is not normal (uniform as in - only one value = 100%). Apologies if it's not the correct technical term to use.

I unfortunately don't have any prior information about the proportion - my instinct is that the % is going to be high, but whether it's 75% or 100% I don't know.

Comment: Not sure whether it's appropriate to compare vs responses to other posts that have only, say, 40 responses due to difference in nature of post + variability of the % of bots in different posts (some can be 100%, others can be 0%).

Comment: you mention that there's no need to cut up into chunks. Would the alternative be to review the entire sample of 4000 all in one chunk, and get a % (say, 1% real)? If I do this, how would I calculate the 95% intervals etc? (I'm only familiar with using standard deviations of all of the chunks to calculate standard error etc). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just for the record, the population sampled from here is finite; so if you sampled a large fraction of it you'd need a confidence interval on a hypergeometric proportion rather than a binomial. For 4k sampled out of 400k of course it's not an issue.

Comment: @kevlaria: Just one 'chunk' & here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: @Scortchi very worthwhile point about the finite population. +1