# Inference in binomial with zero successes and fixed number of trials

Tags: inference, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim \mathsf{Bin}(n, p)$ where $n$ is known and $p$ is to be inferred from the data. Suppose further that $X = 0,$ so that we had no successes.

We can reason in the following way. We want to *reject* any value of $p$ that makes the observed data very unlikely. Let's say we want to mistakenly reject a true $p$ at most $100\alpha$% of the time; in other words, we want to make Type I error with level $\alpha.$ For any given $p,$ $\mathbf{P}(X = 0) = (1-p)^n;$ thus, we reject this $p$ if $(1 - p)^n \leq \alpha.$ This leads to *reject $p$ if $1-\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq p \leq 1$*. Therefore, the value this way of thinking will not reject are in the interval $(0, 1-\alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}).$ Note that when $n \to \infty,$ this interval shrinks, which is good (the more observations we have and if we still have zero successes the more certain we are $p \approx 0$).

> Is this method used in practice?

**To compare:** I ask this because I was checking some materials and these appeal to asymptotic statistics like the Likelihood Ratio, or Rao's score statistic, or Bayesian methods where they choose either a uniform prior or a beta prior. Using Rao's score with $n = 25,$ we would get $(0, 0.132)$ at level $\alpha = 0.05$ while the Bayesian method with uniform prior will give $(0.001, 0.132)$ for a 95% equal-tail posterior interval. The method I described above give $(0, 0.113),$ and the interpretation is simple, any value outside this interval makes what we saw to happen only $5$% of the time or worse (much worse as $p$ grows, actually).

Comment: See [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(statistics)) so in your example of $0$ out of $25$ it suggests an upper figure for the $95\%$ confidence interval of $\frac{3}{25}=0.12$

Comment: @Henry I didn't refer to this interval as a confidence interval since both ends $0$ and $1 - \alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ aren't random. Since both $p$ and $\alpha$ are numbers, the event $0 \leq p \leq 1 - \alpha^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is either the whole sample space or is empty. So I am more confused now that the wikipedia article refers to this interval as a confidence interval.

Comment: If this is a hypothesis test (you say "reject"), you should decide the hypothesis before seeing the data.  If you want a Bayesian analysis, observing no successes will lead to results substantially driven by the prior distribution you assume.  You asked if an such approach as yours is used in practice and I pointed to a well-known example (though it is really an approximation); it is used when either none or all of the observations are successes and so is random when combined with more conventional approaches when some are successes

Comment: Before you perform the experiment, there is some probability of seeing 0 successes and using the Rule of three, or seeing > 0 successes and using some other algorithm.  So the CI is random and data-dependent  If you condition on having seen 0 successes, no it's not, but then neither is calculating a confidence interval when you've seen 1 success (or any other number of successes), given that you've seen 1 success.

Comment: @Henry I am not doing hypothesis test, I don't think. I just want to reject all values of $p$ that would make the observed data too incompatible for these values of $p$ to be the true probability of success. Again, I am thinking in an idealised experiment where each trial is indeed under the same conditions and independent of everything else. In this situation, $p$ is some number and every $0 \leq p < 1$ make the observed data $X = 0$ possible (although, certainly $p \approx 1$ makes it incredibly unlikely). So, my reasoning is different from those of statistics I've read...

Comment: ...For what I understand, in a hypothesis test one has a "test statistic" (i.e. a random variable constructed from the random variables in the hypothesised model) that has a distribution (i.e. the sampling distribution) and one uses the observed value and the theoretical (under the null hypothesis) sampling distribution to obtain the probability of having observed what we saw (i.e. a "p-value"); if this probability is extremely small, (whatever the definition of extreme may be), we say that the null hypothesis is too incompatible with the data, so we reject it. I don't use any statistics tho.

Comment: @jbowman as a matter of fact, I am proceeding backwards. I observed 0 successes and then I reason as stated in the question. So I am sure I am not making hypothesis tests.

Comment: ... sorry, should have written "using the Rule of three or something else such as your proposal"

Comment: You do use a statistic - the number of successes.  In this case that happens to equal 0.  If it had equaled some other number, you would have had a different CI.

Comment: Your CI calculation is, effectively, "If $X=0$ then $CI \leftarrow f_1(0, \alpha, n)$ else $CI \leftarrow f_2(X, \alpha, n)$,"   where $f_1$ is your proposal and $f_2$ is the standard CI calculation.  There's nothing wrong with having a CI calculation that has an if-statement in it.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a philosophical issue whether a $0$ success probability makes sense. For such a problem,
one could use a Bayesian credible interval that gives
an upper bound on the success probability $\theta,$ based on a sequence of say $n = 50$ or $n = 500$ failures in a row.

Suppose your prior distribution is that $\theta$ is
small:  $\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(1, 10)$ and
density $f(\theta) \propto (1-\theta)^9.$

Then after $n=50$ trials with $x=0$ successes, the
binomial likelihood is $g(x|\theta) \propto (1-\theta)^{50}.$

Thus, the posterior density is
$(1-\theta)^9\times (1-\theta)^{50}$ and
the posterior distribution on $\theta$ is
$\mathsf{Beta}(1,60),$ which gives
a one-sided 95% posterior interval estimate of
$(0, 0.049).$ [Using R.]

```
qbeta(.95, 1, 60)
[1] 0.04870291
```

Similarly, with $n = 500$ consecutive failures, the 95% Bayesian posterior interval
estimate would be that $\theta < 0.0059.$

```
qbeta(.95, 1, 510)
[1] 0.005856767
```

*Note:* If you approach this problem without any opinion as to the value of $\theta,$ then you might use the
non-informative Jeffries prior $\mathsf{Beta}(.5,.5).$ Then
95% Bayesian credible intervals for
$50$ and $500$ consecutive failures, respectively, results would be as shown
in R below (rounded to five places).

```
round(qbeta(c(.025,.975), .5, 50.5),6)
[1] 0.000010 0.048758
round(qbeta(c(.025,.975), .5, 500.5),6)
[1] 0.000001 0.005009
```

Comment: The corresponding $\alpha = 0.05$ intervals of the method I mentioned are $(0, 0.058155)$ for $n = 50$ and $(0, 0.00597)$ for $n = 500.$ Very similar intervals (the second one more so), yet I feel to use $(0, 1 - \alpha^{\frac{1}{n}})$ is simpler and the underlying assumptions may be also easier to believe. (There is always the issue of the prior being Beta and so on. And yes, this is not a mathematical point but a philosophical one.) What do you think?

Comment: My note shows that the influence of the prior is not great for sample sizes as large as 50 and (especially) 500. The choice probably depends on one's comfort level with Bayesian or frequentist methods. // I did not intend my Answer to contradict approaches suggested in Comments. For practical purposes results are similar. // The intervals shown in the note are sometimes called Jeffreys confidence intervals and used by frequentists.